# Retrieve nodes where all relationships match a criteria in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to retrieve nodes where none of the relationships to that node have a specific property value. For example, I would like the query to return `foo` in the following example, because both relationships to `foo` have `prop = false`.

`(bar0) -[{prop:false}]-> (foo) <-[{prop:false}]- (bar1)`

On the other hand, I would like the query to return `null` in the following example, because a subset of the relationships to `foo` have `prop = true`.

`(bar0) -[{prop:false}]-> (foo) <-[{prop:true}]- (bar1)`

So far, I've tried:

```
MATCH (foo)-[r]-(bar)
WITH collect(r) as rs, foo, bar
WHERE NONE(r in rs WHERE r.prop = True)
UNWIND rs as r
RETURN foo, bar, r
```

However, this still returns `foo`, it just removes the relationship where `prop = True`.

I also tried using `CASE`, but run into the same problem.

```
MATCH (foo)-[r]-(bar)
WITH collect(r) as rs, foo
RETURN
CASE 
WHEN ALL(r in rs WHERE r.prop=False)
    THEN foo
ELSE null
END
```

Ideally, the query would also return nodes with no relationships as well, but I can also handle that with a separate query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query uses the `EXISTS()` function to avoid having to scan all relationships to every `Foo` node to find the ones of interest. It filters out a `Foo` node as soon as a `true` relationship is found.

```
MATCH (foo:Foo)
WHERE NOT EXISTS((foo)<-[{prop: true}]-())
MATCH (foo)<-[r]-(bar)
RETURN foo, bar, r
```

*This query also uses a directional r*elationship, to conform to the stated data model.

Comment: Note the `EXISTS` function is not really necessary in that use case

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get back only nodes with no `r{prop:True}`, one option is:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (ft:Foo)<-[r{prop:True}]-(b:Bar)
WITH COLLECT(ID(ft)) as ft_ids
MATCH (f:Foo)
WHERE NOT ID(f) IN ft_ids
RETURN DISTINCT (f)
```

Which for sample data:

```
MERGE (a1:Foo {name: 'a1'})  
MERGE (a2:Foo {name: 'a2'}) 
MERGE (b1:Bar {name: 'b1'})
MERGE (b2:Bar {name: 'b2'}) 
MERGE (b3:Bar {name: 'b3'}) 
MERGE (a3:Foo {name: 'a3'})  
MERGE (a4:Foo {name: 'a3'})  

MERGE (b1)-[:POINTS{prop:true}]-(a1)
MERGE (b2)-[:POINTS{prop:true}]-(a1)
MERGE (b3)-[:POINTS{prop:false}]-(a2)
MERGE (b1)-[:POINTS{prop:false}]-(a2)
MERGE (b2)-[:POINTS{prop:false}]-(a3)
MERGE (b1)-[:POINTS{prop:true}]-(a3)
```

returns:

```
╒═════════════╕
│"f"          │
╞═════════════╡
│{"name":"a2"}│
├─────────────┤
│{"name":"a4"}│
└─────────────┘
```

It is not clear which relationships and `bars` you want to get back...